# How to get the length of a segment in TikZ in a macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

My problem is exactly what [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74718/180693) stated. However, I can't use the `let` operator due to some reasons.

So how can I define a command `\getlength` so that `\getlength{a}{b}` will return the length of `(a) -- (b)`?

Current not working example – I think that is because two Ti*k*Z pictures are nested, which is never good:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\getlength#1#2{
  \path[overlay] ($(#1)-(#2)$);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\myx}{\myy}
  \pgfmathparse{veclen(\myx, \myy)}\pgfmathresult
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (b) -- (5,0) coordinate (c) -- (1,4) coordinate (a) -- cycle;
  % It should work in both, but sadly it is not working in any of these
  \path node {\getlength{a}{b}};
  \draw (0,0) circle (\getlength{a}{b});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are loading `calc`, so

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (b) -- (5,0) coordinate (c) -- (1,4) coordinate (a) -- cycle;
  \draw let \p1=($(b)-(a)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
  (0,0) node {\n1}  circle [radius=\n1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is, however, possible to create a function `distance` that returns the distance between two named coordinates. It can be used, and gets parsed, like any other function. It does not create a path. **HOWEVER, MY PREVIOUS EXAMPLE USING IT IN A PATH WAS DANGEROUS AND IS IN GENERAL WRONG.** I thank JouleV top reporting this to me! It even works outside of `tikzpicture`s. (This function here is tailored to resemble your original function.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{distance}{2}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfextractx{\pgf@xa}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@ya}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
\pgfextractx{\pgf@xb}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@yb}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
\pgfmathparse{veclen(\pgf@xa-\pgf@xb,\pgf@ya-\pgf@yb)}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (b) -- (5,0) coordinate (c) -- (1,4) coordinate (a) -- cycle;
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydist}{distance("a","b")}
  \path node {\mydist};
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=\mydist pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: I agree with Alain Matthes that `veclen` is imprecise. This is just to mention that you do not need `xfp` to solve the problem, computing the Euclidean distance is sufficient. And I also think that `tkz-euclide` is great, but one does not need it in order to convert the result to cm, a simple `\pgfmathparse{<whatever>/1cm}` is sufficient.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{distance}{2}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfextractx{\pgf@xa}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@ya}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
\pgfextractx{\pgf@xb}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@yb}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
\pgfmathparse{sqrt((\pgf@xa-\pgf@xb)*(\pgf@xa-\pgf@xb)+(\pgf@ya-\pgf@yb)*(\pgf@ya-\pgf@yb))}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (b) -- (40pt,0)
              coordinate (c) -- (40pt,30pt)
              coordinate (a) -- cycle;
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydistance}{distance("a","b")}            
  \path node 
  {$\pgfmathprintnumber{\mydistance}\,\mathrm{pt}=
  \pgfmathparse{\mydistance/1cm}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\mathrm{cm}$};
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius={\mydistance pt}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is, though an advantage of `xfp`: it does not collapse when one has large distances. The same is true for the `fpu` library, which is made for this and used e.g. in `pgfplots`. One can use [this in "ordinary Ti*k*Z, too](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518311). This yields a version that is immune to large values, and (rather) precise.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\newcommand{\pgfmathparseFPU}[1]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathparse{#1}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{distance}{2}{%
\begingroup%
\pgfextractx{\pgf@xa}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@ya}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
\pgfextractx{\pgf@xb}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
\pgfextracty{\pgf@yb}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}%
\pgfmathparseFPU{sqrt((\pgf@xa-\pgf@xb)*(\pgf@xa-\pgf@xb)+(\pgf@ya-\pgf@yb)*(\pgf@ya-\pgf@yb))}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (b) -- (40pt,0)
              coordinate (c) -- (40pt,30pt)
              coordinate (a) -- cycle;
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydistance}{distance("a","b")}            
  \path node 
  {$\pgfmathprintnumber{\mydistance}\,\mathrm{pt}=
  \pgfmathparse{\mydistance/1cm}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\mathrm{cm}$};
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius={distance("a","b")}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for `\pgfmathsmuggle`. I'd never seen this before!

Comment: @Andrew It is used to smuggle the result out of the group. That is, inside the group/function you can do whatever you like, but you only want to smuggle out the result. Basically all of the functions in pgf use some variant of this,

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I found it in the manual. I've never tried reading the pgf code...

Comment: When I started working on tkz, `fpu` didn't exist.  :( I have a problem with your last code. It does not compile. I used  `\pgfmathparse{distance("a","b")}\let\dd\pgfmathresult
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=\dd pt];` to get the circle

Comment: I got the same error with the two code `Latex Error: ./distance_cat.tex:17 Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/"b")`

Comment: @AlainMatthes I do not get these errors. I use a very up-to-date TeXLive 2019 installation and pgf 3.1.5.

Comment: I update pgf from 3.1.4 to 3.1.5 and the error disappeared (but why ???)

Comment: @AlainMatthes It is more the question why you got them in the old version. There is no reasonable way the parser should try to find a key `/tikz/"b"`. The declaration of the function does not even require Ti*k*Z, just pgf. Strange.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `\pgfgetlastxy` extracts the `x` and `y` coordinates as dimensions so you need to first define these dimensions. I think it is also good to define another dimension for the actual result. If you define these new dimensions then your code pretty much works.

For no good reason, I prefer defining a node to a path, so I rewrote your code so that `\getlength{a}{b}` sets the length `\mylength`, which you can use where you wish:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newdimen\mypointx
\newdimen\mypointy
\newdimen\mylength
\def\getlength#1#2{
  \node (#1#2) at ($ (#1)-(#2) $){};% define a point at (#1)-(#2_
  \pgfgetlastxy{\mypointx}{\mypointy}% extract the coordinates
  \pgfmathsetlength\mylength{veclen(\mypointx, \mypointy)}% compute the length
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (b) -- (5,0) coordinate (c) -- (1,4) coordinate (a) -- cycle;
  % It should work in both, but sadly it is not working in any of these
  \getlength{a}{b};
  \draw (0,0) circle (\mylength);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the  expected:

[image]

I was not sure what `\path node {\getlength{a}{b}};` was meant to do because, for example, `\path node 1;` is not valid syntax. Did you mean something like `\path node (\getlength{a}{b},0){};`?

Finally, it is not strictly necessary to use another length like `\mylength` above. You could instead use a standard macro with

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\mymacro{veclen(\mypointx, \mypointy)}
```

or even

```
\pgfmathparse{veclen(\mypointx, \mypointy)}
```

that you use in commands like

```
\draw (0,0) circle (\mymacro);

and

\draw (0,0) circle (\pgfmathresult);
```

respectively. However, as far as I can see you cannot put `\pgfmathresult` at the end of the `\getlength` and then use this inside a command like

```
\draw (0,0) circle (\getlength{a}{b});
```

as this always returns an error. I suspect is an expansion issue.

Comment: I am really sorry for un-accepting your answer, but I have to admit that Schrodinger's cat's answer is more helpful to me than yours (your answer is still great, though!)

Comment: @NP. It's the better answer:)

Answer (score 6):

The only problem is the result with `veclen` from `pgfmath`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xfp} 
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}{%
\begingroup%
  \pgfmath@x#1pt\relax%
  \pgfmath@y#2pt\relax%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
  \edef\tkz@temp@a{\fpeval{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@xa}}}
  \edef\tkz@temp@b{\fpeval{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@ya}}}
  \edef\tkz@temp@sum{\fpeval{%
    (\tkz@temp@a*\tkz@temp@a+\tkz@temp@b*\tkz@temp@b)}}
  \edef\tkzFPMathLen{\fpeval{sqrt(\tkz@temp@sum)}}
  \pgfmath@returnone\tkzFPMathLen pt%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (b) -- (40pt,0)
              coordinate (c) -- (40pt,30pt)
              coordinate (a) -- cycle;
  \draw let \p1=($(b)-(a)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
  (0,0) node {\n1}  circle [radius=\n1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With **tkz-euclide** you have the macro `\tkzCalcLength`

```
\documentclass[border=.25cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,4){A}
    \tkzCalcLength(A,B)\tkzGetLength{dAB}
    \node {\dAB pt};
    \tkzCalcLength[cm](A,B)\tkzGetLength{dAB}
    \node at (2,0) {\dAB cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I sometimes stumbled over the `veclen` problem. +1. Do you know why it is implemented in the way it is? Just computing the Euclidean distance naively doesn't have these inaccuracies.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat No I don't know..  Overall you need precision and efficiency.and like the example on this page shows , the inaccuracy is minor. `veclen` is used in a lot of libraries and speed is more important than precision. `veclen` with  fp or xfp is an option with tkz-euclide. The best way will be to use lua. This is why I prefer to do the definitions and calculations first before the drawings. I hope to be able to do the first parts with lua.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `\n1={sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)}` as a substitute for `veclen`?