# Tikz: draw a path the same length as another path starting at a specific coordinate and intersecting a given point

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have some tikz code that draws a triangle with labelled verticies.

I would like to draw a line that starts at the origin, intersecting the point labelled P, and has a length equal to the edge labelled A.

I figure that the calc library is what I want for this, but I'm having trouble working out how to feed it the length of A...

Here is my code so far, with my best guess at what I think the edge I want to draw command will look like:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc, through, backgrounds}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]


% layout some coordinates for a triangle
\coordinate (P) at ($(0,0) + (rand,rand)$);
\coordinate (Q) at ($(2,-2) + .5*(rand, rand)$);
\coordinate (R) at ($(-2, -2) + .5*(rand, rand)$);
%convienience for finding the centre
\coordinate (PQR) at ($(P)+(Q)+(R)$);
\coordinate (O) at ($1/3*(PQR)$);

%draw triangle
\draw[name path=A] (P) -- (Q);
\draw[name path=B] (Q) -- (R);
\draw[name path=C] (R) -- (P);

%labels
\node at (O) {$O$};
\node at (P) [above=2pt]{$P$};
\node at (Q) [right=2pt]{$Q$};
\node at (R) [left=2pt]{$R$};

\node at ($(P)!.5!(Q)$) [above right=1em]{$\mathbf{A}$};

%draw a path of length (A) from (O), passing through (P)
%\draw[name path=U] (O) -- ($(O)! !(B)$)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives me this output
[image]

Comment: some clarity is desired with a hand drawn sketch of the output

Comment: With `tkz-euclide`, you can get the length of a segment with `\tkzCalcLength` macro. And not related, but finding the centroid is shorter with `\coordinate (O) at (barycentric cs:P=1,Q=1,R=1) ;`.

Comment: Thanks SebGlav, I didn't know about that centroid command, I figured there might be a better way. Also my desired output is the output yeilded by sebglavs answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tkz-euclide`, you may use this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    
        % Coordinates for a triangle
        \coordinate (P) at ($(0,0) + (rand,rand)$);
        \coordinate (Q) at ($(2,-2) + .5*(rand, rand)$);
        \coordinate (R) at ($(-2, -2) + .5*(rand, rand)$);
        \coordinate (O) at (barycentric cs:P=1,Q=1,R=1) ;
        
        % Draw triangle
        \draw (P) -- (Q) node[midway,above,sloped] {dist $=A$}  -- (R) -- cycle;
        
        \tkzDrawPoints(P,Q,R,O)
        
        % Labels
        \node at (O) [left=2pt]{$O$};
        \node at (P) [above right]{$P$};
        \node at (Q) [right=2pt]{$Q$};
        \node at (R) [left=2pt]{$R$};
        
        % Calculate length of segment PQ and label as dPQ
        \tkzCalcLength(P,Q)\tkzGetLength{dPQ}
        
        % Create some point on a circle centred on O and with radius = PQ length
        \tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=90,center=O,radius=\dPQ pt]
        \tkzGetPoint{I}
        
        % Find intersection between line OP and previous circle
        % Two points, but only one is useful
        \tkzInterLC(O,P)(O,I) \tkzGetPoints{D}{E}
        
        % Draw the segment from O, passing through P, the length of PQ
        \draw[dashed,blue] (O) -- (E) node[pos=0.7,left] {dist$=A$};
        
        \tkzDrawPoints(E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: centroid and calc length]

**EDIT**
Taking advantage of this other clever option (apart from `veclen` which I definitely would not use), here comes another shorter version, using `tikz-euclide` to compute the segment length and a simpler implementation of the drawn segment.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    
        % Coordinates for a triangle
        \coordinate (P) at ($(0,0) + (rand,rand)$);
        \coordinate (Q) at ($(2,-2) + .5*(rand, rand)$);
        \coordinate (R) at ($(-2, -2) + .5*(rand, rand)$);
        \coordinate (O) at (barycentric cs:P=1,Q=1,R=1) ;
        
        % Draw triangle
        \draw (P) -- (Q) node[midway,above,sloped] {dist $=A$}  -- (R) -- cycle;
        
        \tkzDrawPoints(P,Q,R,O)
        
        % Labels
        \node at (O) [left=2pt]{$O$};
        \node at (P) [above right]{$P$};
        \node at (Q) [right=2pt]{$Q$};
        \node at (R) [left=2pt]{$R$};
        
        % Calculate length of segment PQ
        \tkzCalcLength(P,Q)\tkzGetLength{dPQ}
        
        % Draw the segment from O, passing through P, the length of PQ
        \draw[orange,thick,dashed] (O)--++ ($(O)!\dPQ pt!(P)-(O)$) coordinate[at end] (E);

        \tkzDrawPoints(E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)

    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: version 2]

Comment: Just one quick thing, why would you definitly not use veclen? Care to add a citation or side sentence on that? Otherwise thanks for all the help, this is exactly what I needed

Comment: @AndrewMicallef, as @SebGlav points out in the comments of my response (below), `veclen` is slightly imprecise. It can be off by a small fraction of a percent. Specifically, in a 50pt line segment, as the hypotenuse of a 30pt, 40pt, 50pt right triangle, `veclen` measures 49.99512pt. For most uses, this is not noticeable, so I wouldn't say definitely not to use it, but @SebGlav's solution is indeed more precise. Another way is to use `sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)` to measure the length.

Comment: Ah, I see, I'm still new to tikz, so had no idea how to capture the coordinates... but I think you clarified that in your answer, by using the let command so thankyou for that too

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the length of the "vector" `(\x,\y)` using `sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)`. Then use the construction

`($(A)!<len>!(B)-(A)$)`

to create a vector from (A) in the direction of (B) – (A) with length `<len>`:

[image]

Here, the blue line has endpoints (A) = (1,0) and (B) = (3,1). The red line is drawn from (C) = (1,1) through (D) = (2,2) with the length of the line from (A) to (B) using the code

```
\draw[red,thick] let\p1=($(B)-(A)$) in (C)--++($(C)!sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)!(D)-(C)$);
```

The `let` command assigns to `\p1` the "vector" from (A) to (B), which automatically assigns its x and y components to `\x1` and `\y1`.

If you wish, you could define a command `\thru` that takes 5 arguments, one optional:

```
\newcommand{\thru}[5][]{\draw[#1] let\p1=($#5-#4$) in #2--++($#2!sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)!#3-#2$);}
```

The optional argument would be any `tikz` attributes you want. The first required argument is your starting point, the second is the through point, the third and fourth are the endpoints of the segment whose length you want.

So `\thru[green,thick]{(2,1)}{(3,2)}{(A)}{(B)}` would draw the thick green line from (2,1) through (3,2) having the length of segment (A)--(B).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\thru}[5][]{\draw[#1] let\p1=($#5-#4$) in #2--++($#2!sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)!#3-#2$);}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (4,3);
\coordinate(A) at (1,0);
\coordinate(B) at (3,1);
\coordinate(C) at (1,1);
\coordinate(D) at (2,2);
\draw[blue,thick] (A)--(B);

\draw[red,thick] let\p1=($(B)-(A)$) in (C)--++($(C)!sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)!(D)-(C)$);
\thru[green,thick]{(2,1)}{(3,2)}{(A)}{(B)}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's known that `veclen` is sometimes very sloppy. That's why I prefer using `tkz-euclide` to get a segment length.

Comment: @SebGlav, in what sense is `veclen` sloppy? I've never experienced any issues using it in this fashion (with a vector quantity for input). Can you point me to an example?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521541/how-to-get-the-length-of-a-segment-in-tikz-in-a-macro (actually, I'm used to `tkz-euclide` and just dropped any other possibilities which coexist)

Comment: @SebGlav, thanks. That's somewhat bizarre. Is there a reason not to use `sqrt(\x1^2+\y1^2)`? That doesn't seem to have the same issue. I always assumed `veclen` was just a shortcut for the `sqrt` calculation. But apparently not. I edited my response.

Comment: Actually, `sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)` is better.