# tikz: `! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function` in for loop but works outside of loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am working on drawing a triangle and some vectors using tikz and tikz-euclid.

I want to draw each edge of my triangle as a vector, with length equal to the length of the edge, located at the midpoint, O, and perpendicular to the relevant edge. Almost like what I have sketched so far, but instead of intersecting the midpoints, the vectors should be perpendicular.

I'm trying to get my head around tikz syntax here, and had tikz-euclid suggested to me from a previous question. Because I am drawing more than one vector I would like to put the draw functions in a loop, like so:

```
% 1. Coordinates of the line segment midpoints, E,F,G
% 2. get lengths of vectors A, B, C (as, dA, dB, dC)
% 3. draw the vectors from O passing through relevant midpoint
\foreach \mid/\tip/\tail/\vector in {E/P/Q/A, F/Q/R/B, G/R/P/C}{
    \coordinate (\mid) at ($(\tip)!0.5!(\tail)$);
            
    % Calculate length of segments and label as dA, dB, dC 
    \tkzCalcLength(\tip,\tail)\tkzGetLength{d\vector}
            
    %THIS throws an error:
    %> ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `dApt' (in 'dApt').
    \draw[->] (O)--++ ($(O)!d\vector pt!(\mid)-(O)$);
}
```

But this has thrown an error:

`! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function 'dApt' (in 'dApt')`

However, re-writting the code just after the loop:

```tex
\draw[->] (O)--++ ($(O)!\dA pt!(E)-(O)$);
\draw[->] (O)--++ ($(O)!\dB pt!(F)-(O)$);
\draw[->] (O)--++ ($(O)!\dC pt!(G)-(O)$);
```

Produces what I want. Is there a way to re-write this so that it works within the `\foreach` loop? I figure there is some escape sequencing or something messing with the line in the loop. But I can't figure out how to get it right. Any ideas?

For reference the code I have generates something that looks like this, and for the moment if I get something that looks like this out but done in a loop I will be happy.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc,through,backgrounds}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    
        % Coordinates for a triangle
        \coordinate (P) at ($(0,0) + (rand,rand)$);
        \coordinate (Q) at ($(2,-2) + .5*(rand, rand)$);
        \coordinate (R) at ($(-2, -2) + .5*(rand, rand)$);
        \coordinate (O) at (barycentric cs:P=1,Q=1,R=1) ;
        
        
        % 1. Coordinates of the line segment midpoints, E,F,G
        % 2. get lengths of vectors A, B, C (as, dA, dB, dC)
        % 3. draw the vectors from O passing through relevant midpoint
        \foreach \mid/\tip/\tail/\vector in {E/P/Q/A, F/Q/R/B, G/R/P/C}{
            \coordinate (\mid) at ($(\tip)!0.5!(\tail)$);
            
           % Calculate length of segments and label as dA, dB, dC 
            \tkzCalcLength(\tip,\tail)\tkzGetLength{d\vector}
            
            %THIS throws an error:
            %> ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `dApt' (in 'dApt').
            %\draw[->] (O)--++ ($(O)!d\vector pt!(\mid)-(O)$);
        }
        
        % This works
        % Draw the vectors A,B,C from O, passing through E,F,G respectivley
        \draw[->] (O)--++ ($(O)!\dA pt!(E)-(O)$);
        \draw[->] (O)--++ ($(O)!\dB pt!(F)-(O)$);
        \draw[->] (O)--++ ($(O)!\dC pt!(G)-(O)$);
        
        
        \draw [thin] (P) -- node[midway,sloped] {$||$}(Q) --node[midway,sloped] {$||$} (R) --node[midway,sloped] {$||$} cycle;
        
        \tkzDrawPoints(P,Q,R,O)
        
        % Labels
        \node at (O) [left=2pt]{$O$};
        \node at (P) [above right]{$P$};
        \node at (Q) [right=2pt]{$Q$};
        \node at (R) [left=2pt]{$R$};
       
        % midpoints
        \begin{scope}[black!40]
        \node at (E) [below left=.5em]{$E$};
        \node at (F) [below=.5em]{$F$};
        \node at (G) [below right=.5em]{$G$};
        \end{scope}

    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of solving your issue is to ask less. Especially store the result in your `foreach` loop into a simple variable (here, I used `\len`).
Now, if you want to reuse these length, you can still write what you did in the first place, but it won't work into your loop (and I currently don't know why, maybe Alain Matthes would know, as the package creator).

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc,through,backgrounds}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    
        % Coordinates for a triangle
        \coordinate (P) at ($(0,0) + (rand,rand)$);
        \coordinate (Q) at ($(2,-2) + .5*(rand, rand)$);
        \coordinate (R) at ($(-2, -2) + .5*(rand, rand)$);
        \coordinate (O) at (barycentric cs:P=1,Q=1,R=1) ;
        
        
        % 1. Coordinates of the line segment midpoints, E,F,G
        % 2. get lengths of vectors A, B, C (as, dA, dB, dC)
        % 3. draw the vectors from O passing through relevant midpoint
        \foreach [count=\i] \mid/\tip/\tail/\v in {E/P/Q/A, F/Q/R/B, G/R/P/C}{
            \coordinate (\mid) at ($(\tip)!0.5!(\tail)$);
            
           % Calculate length of segments and label as dA, dB, dC (NOT)
           
            \tkzCalcLength(\tip,\tail)\tkzGetLength{len}    % PROBLEM SOLVED
            \draw[->] (O)--++ ($(O)!\len pt!(\mid)-(O)$);   % PROBLEM SOLVED
        }        
        
        \draw [thin] (P) -- node[midway,sloped] {$||$}(Q) --node[midway,sloped] {$||$} (R) --node[midway,sloped] {$||$} cycle;
        
        \tkzDrawPoints(P,Q,R,O)
        
        % Labels
        \node at (O) [left=2pt]{$O$};
        \node at (P) [above right]{$P$};
        \node at (Q) [right=2pt]{$Q$};
        \node at (R) [left=2pt]{$R$};
       
        % midpoints
        \begin{scope}[black!40]
        \node at (E) [below left=.5em]{$E$};
        \node at (F) [below=.5em]{$F$};
        \node at (G) [below right=.5em]{$G$};
        \end{scope}

    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: the drawings]

Answer (score 2):

Turns out tikz-euclid was getting in the way.

[This answer by @Sandy G earlier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583135/234710) put me on the path to the right solution.

replacing the `tkz-euclid` code with

```tex
\draw[->, blue] let 
                \p1 = ($(\tip)-(\tail)$)
            in
                (O)--++($(O)!sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)!(\mid)-(O)$);
```

allowed me to put the draw command in a loop without too much of a hassle.

Thus my code became the following, which produced this picture.

[image]

```tex
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    
        % Coordinates for a triangle
        \coordinate (P) at ($(0,0) + (rand,rand)$);
        \coordinate (Q) at ($(2,-2) + .5*(rand, rand)$);
        \coordinate (R) at ($(-2, -2) + .5*(rand, rand)$);
        \coordinate (O) at (barycentric cs:P=1,Q=1,R=1) ;
        
        
        % 1. Coordinates of the line segment midpoints, E,F,G
        % 2. draw the vectors from O passing through relevant midpoint
        \foreach \mid/\tip/\tail/\vector in {E/P/Q/A, F/Q/R/B, G/R/P/C}{
            \coordinate (\mid) at ($(\tip)!0.5!(\tail)$);
            
            \draw[->, blue] let 
                \p1 = ($(\tip)-(\tail)$)
            in
                (O)--++($(O)!sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)!(\mid)-(O)$);
        }
        
        % Draw triangle, and midpoint markers
        \draw [thin] (P) -- node[midway,sloped] {$||$}(Q) --node[midway,sloped] {$||$} (R) --node[midway,sloped] {$||$} cycle;
        
        % Labels: verticies
        \node at (O) [left=2pt]{$O$};
        \node at (P) [above right]{$P$};
        \node at (Q) [right=2pt]{$Q$};
        \node at (R) [left=2pt]{$R$};
        
        % Labels: midpoints
        \begin{scope}[black!40]
        \node at (E) [below left=.5em]{$E$};
        \node at (F) [below=.5em]{$F$};
        \node at (G) [below right=.5em]{$G$};
        \end{scope}

    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While this does solve my immediate problem, i think I would like to use `tkz-euclid` in the future, so any ideas on how to rewrite the offending line of code would still be appreciated