# TiKZ: trouble with angles ! Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again>

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to draw the arc of an angle between two lines in tikz. I'm using the angles library and have pretty much copied the example from the manual, but when I try to label the arc, I get the following error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \theta
l.29 ...c [draw, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=3]{angle=P--V--Q};
```

I am following the syntax from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219039/234710).
But I have the same trouble using the syntax from the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) pg 570.

Removing the label allows me to draw the arc no trouble. But I would really like to put a theta in my diagram. I thought it might be an escaping issue so I tried labelling with `"$t$"`, and then `"t"`. In the last case the error tells me tikz doesn't know of the label `t`.

[image]

my drawing code is below

```tex
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}

\begin{document}

    
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \def \radius{3.5}
      \coordinate (V) at ($(0,0)!\radius cm!rand*45:(0,\radius)$);
      
      \path (-\radius, 0) coordinate(P) -- 
                   coordinate[midway](O)
                   (\radius, 0) coordinate(Q);
      
      % Draw semicircle
      \draw (Q) arc(0:180:\radius1);
      \draw[shorten <=-5mm, shorten >=-5mm] (P) -- (Q);
      
      %draw an arc starting at [partway from V to Q], to[ partway from V to P]
      \draw [color=blue] (P)--(V)--(Q);
      \pic [draw, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=3] {angle=P--V--Q};

      
      \node at (O) [below]  {$O$};
      \node at (P) [below]  {$P$};
      \node at (Q) [below]  {$Q$};
      \node at (V) [above]  {$V$};
      
      \foreach \p in {O,P,Q, V}{
        \fill (\p) circle (1pt);
      }\
      
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need to add quotes `\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,quotes}`. Then it processes normaly.

Comment: that fixed it, um should I delete the qestion or would you like to write an answer?

Comment: I think writing an answer is not necessary for such simple problems/error. Still it may help someone else who have a similar problem in the future (e.g. [Deleting a question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/deleting-a-question-thats-likely-to-be-unimportant-very-soon)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is solved by @Roland comment, so here are some off-topic suggestions:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                calc,
                quotes} % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\def \radius{3.5}
\coordinate (V) at ($(0,0)!\radius cm!rand*45:(0,\radius)$);
\path (-\radius, 0) coordinate[label=below:$P$] (P)  % <---
                --  coordinate[label=below:$O$] (O) (\radius, 0) % <---
                    coordinate[label=below:$Q$] (Q); % <---
% draw semicircle
\draw (Q) arc(0:180:\radius);
\draw[shorten <=-5mm, shorten >=-5mm] (P) -- (Q);
% draw triangles's cathetus
\draw [color=blue, semithick] (P)--(V)--(Q);
% draw angle
\pic [draw=blue, text=red, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle=P--V--Q}; % <---
% dots      
\foreach \p in {O,P,Q, V}{\fill (\p) circle[radius=1.5pt];}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** colored angle as you desired in your comment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clean up suggestions. As an aside how would I make the label theta a different color to the arc (say blue and red respectivley)? Should I open a seperate question for that

Comment: nvm `pic ["${\color{red}\theta}$", draw=blue, angle eccentricity=1.5] {angle=P--V--Q}`

Answer (score 0):

Even if the previous answer is such a clean solution, I think you would definitely discover the `tkz-euclide` package which is extremely versatile when it comes to drawing mathematical geometric figures. I didn't rewrite all your figure with `tkz-euclid` commands, but you could save time by doing it for your future projects. Here, the only change is for drawing and labeling the angle.

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

    
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \def \radius{3.5}
      \coordinate (V) at ($(0,0)!\radius cm!rand*45:(0,\radius)$);
      
      \path (-\radius, 0) coordinate(P) -- 
                   coordinate[midway](O)
                   (\radius, 0) coordinate(Q);
      
      % Draw semicircle
      \draw (Q) arc(0:180:\radius1);
      \draw[shorten <=-5mm, shorten >=-5mm] (P) -- (Q);
      
      %draw an arc starting at [partway from V to Q], to[ partway from V to P]
      \draw [color=blue] (P)--(V)--(Q);
      
      %-------------- Here's the use of tkz-euclide-----
      \tkzMarkAngle[color=blue,mark=none,size=.5](P,V,Q)
      \tkzLabelAngle[color=red,pos=0.8](P,V,Q){$\theta$}
      %-------------------------------------------------

      
      \node at (O) [below]  {$O$};
      \node at (P) [below]  {$P$};
      \node at (Q) [below]  {$Q$};
      \node at (V) [above]  {$V$};
      
      \foreach \p in {O,P,Q, V}{
        \fill (\p) circle (1pt);
      }\
      
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: tkzMarkAngle]

Comment: ah, thanks for that.
I poked my nose into tikz-euclid after you suggested it the other day, but immediatly ran into trouble in a [foreach loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583179/tikz-package-pgf-math-error-unknown-function-in-for-loop-but-works-outside) which I found I could resolve by not using euclid. Perhaps you might care to take a look at that question?